# Measuring mystery distances

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Some puzzling distances:

If 110 to 39 is 1046km

And 105 to 115 is 114km

Then how far is 97 to 38?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An approximate answer for the distance from 97 to 38:

> Based on where the elements with these atomic numbers were named after →
>  Berkeley, USA (Berkelium - 97) to Strontian, Scotland (Strontium - 38) ~ 7950 km

If 110 to 39 is 1046km, and 105 to 115 is 114km correspond to:

> Darmstadt, Germany (Darmstadtium -110) to Ytterby, Sweden (Yttrium - 39)
>   Dubna, Russia (Dubnium - 105) to Moscow, Russia (Moscovium - 115)